# How do I simply parse a public Google calendar?

Tags: android, rss, google-calendar-api, saxparser

I have been able to parse the events from a Google calendar for a specific date using the AndroidSaxParser for the rss format. However, there are several extra pieces of information I cannot seem to seperate, like beginning and ending times. I end up displaying this ugly piece of xml code for the entry's description. Does anyone have a solution to this that doesn't involve getting an authorization key from Google? I don't intend to write anything to the calendar.